# How to support persistent in EventAggregator?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism, eventaggregator

I am using EventAggregator in Prism, and I want the events persisted, which means when a client subscribes a certain event, the aggregator published the previous events that missed to the client. Is there a way to support this?

I know this sounds more like a message queue or something. But the system has already heavily coupled with EventAggregator thus I want this framework can allow me to selectively persist some events without too much modification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following article discusses a "store and forward" EventAggregator implementation which sounds like an excellent match for your scenario i.e. clients being able to catch up with events they may have missed:

http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2008/11/adding-store-and-forward-support-to-the-prism-eventaggregator/

Comment: The link is not working for me. 'You don't have permission to access this resource.Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe'. Showing this message